# Orders placed by a buyer are not showing to sellers Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

I'm trying to get orders placed by buyers to be seen by the respective seller but it does not show anything.

I have tried for hours to solve this problem but I'm still stuck.

This is my model **Order.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Order extends Model
{
    //protected $table = 'orders';
    protected $fillable =  [
        'user_id', 'shipping_email', 'shipping_name', 'shipping_city',    'shipping_phone', 'billing_subtotal', 'billing_total',
    ];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Products_model')->withPivot('quantity');
    }

    public function orders(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\OrderProduct', 'order_id');
    }
}
```

This is my **OrderProduct.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class OrderProduct extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'order_product';
    protected $fillable = ['order_id', 'product_id', 'quantity'];

    public function products()
    { 
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Products_model');
    }
}
```

This is my **User.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'Seller'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token', 
    ];

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Products_model::class);
    }

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function orders()
    {
        $this->hasManyThrough(Order::class, Products_model::class, 'user_id', 'product_id');
    }
}
```

And finally here is my viewOrder function in **ProductController**

```
//Orders View Function
public function viewOrders(User $user)
{
    $products = Products_model::where('user_id', '=', $user->id)->get();
    $orders = [];
    foreach($products as $product){
        array_merge($orders, $product->order);
    }
    //dd( $products);
    return view('orders')->with(compact('orders'));
}
```

I need every seller(user) who listed the product to receive the order when another buyer(user) purchase. so far it shows 
"Order ID   Order Date  Customer Name   Customer City   Customer Phone

Answer (score 0):

On order model, You have a relation with a user, which means you have the buyers info. 
But You don't have any relation for the seller.

> So add a relation for the seller.

note: I assume that both buyer and seller are `User`

You must add a relation for a buyer and relation for a seller (don't forget to add them on database too. That means you need to add `buyer_id` and `seller_id` field on `orders table`).

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Order extends Model
{
     //protected $table = 'orders';
     protected $fillable =  [
        'buyer_id', 'seller_id', 'shipping_email', 'shipping_name', 'shipping_city',    'shipping_phone', 'billing_subtotal', 'billing_total',
     ];    


     public function products()
     {
         return $this->belongsToMany('App\Products_model')->withPivot('quantity');
     }

     public function orders(){
          return $this->hasMany('App\OrderProduct', 'order_id');
     }
     public function buyer()
     {
         return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'id', 'buyer_id');
     }

     public function seller()
     {
         return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'id', 'seller_id');
     }
  }
```

Add these two relations to the User model. so you can call them easily.

```
 public function buys() {
    $this->hasMany(Order::class, 'buyer_id', 'id');
 }
 public function sells() {
     $this->hasMany(Order::class, 'seller_id', 'id');
 }
```

//Orders View Function

```
public function viewOrders(User $user) {
    $products = Products_model::where('user_id', '=', $user->id)->get();
    // all sells
    $sells = $user->sells;
    // all buys
    $buys = $user->buys;

}
```

In view, you can loop it like,

```
@foreach($sells as $sell) 
    {{ $sell->orders }} //for orders.
    {{ $sell->products }} //for product
    @foreach($sell->orders as $order)
        {{ $order->product }} //single product
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: yes you're correct both seller and buyer are users. So how do i add that relationship?

Comment: in products table i have only user_id, i don't have buyer_id or seller_id because any user can buy  and sell. @hasan05

Comment: I think you need to change database structure. cause you want to buy from **a users account (seller) to another users account (buyer).** If i didnt understand wrong. Aint i?

Comment: So I have to add seller_id and buyer_id column in products table?

Comment: No, they are need to add on orders table. Can read the whole answer again? and try the steps? If it doesnt solve your problem, then let me know specific. what and where you face problem.

Comment: By the way. I dont think you need an *user_id* field on Products_model for any order. for the above answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194936/discussion-between-hasan05-and-joh).

Comment: Not yet@hasan05

Comment: You had a different issue, I saw in another question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56600859/how-to-query-seller-id-from-products-table-in-database-laravel/56603420#56603420
But, for your first step, is this an accepted answer?

Comment: No is not @hasan05