# How to query Seller Id from Products table in database Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm working on a project where users can sell and also buy products, and in my database there are two tables(orders and order products table)in orders tables there's a buyer_id and seller_id. So if a user buys product it shows buyer_id now the problem comes to seller_id. It doesn't show the seller_id.

Here is my code.

User.php

```
 class User extends Authenticatable
{
use Notifiable;

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password', 'Seller'
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
 protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token', 
  ];

//public function isSeller() {
 //   return $this->seller;
//}

 public function products()
 {
  return $this->hasMany(Products_model::class);
 }
/**
 * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $casts = [
    'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
 ];

 public function orders()
 {
   return $this->hasManyThrough(Order::class, Products_model::class, 'buyer_id', 'seller_id', 'product_id');
  }

 public function orderFromBuyers()
 {
  $this->hasManyThrough(OrderProduct::class, Products_model::class, 'buyer_id', 'product_id');
 }

 public function orderFromSellers()
 {
    $this->hasManyThrough(OrderProduct::class, Products_model::class, 'seller_id', 'product_id');
 }
 }
```

Products_model.php

```
 <?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class products_model extends Model
{
protected $table='products';
protected $primaryKey='id';
protected $fillable= ['seller_id','pro_name','pro_price','pro_info','image','stock','category_id'];
}
```

OrderProduct.php

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class OrderProduct extends Model
{
protected $table = 'order_product';
protected $fillable = ['order_id', 'buyer_id', 'seller_id','product_id', 'quantity'];

public function products()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Products_model');
}

public function buyer()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'id', 'buyer_id');
}

public function seller()
 {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'id', 'seller_id');
 }
  }
```

Order.php

```
 <?php
 namespace App;
 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
 class Order extends Model
 {
//protected $table = 'orders';
protected $fillable =  [
    'shipping_email', 'shipping_name', 'shipping_city', 'shipping_phone', 'billing_subtotal', 'billing_total',
];

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}

public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Products_model')->withPivot('quantity');
}

 public function orders(){
     return $this->hasMany('App\OrderProduct', 'order_id');
 }
```

My store Function

```
  public function store(Request $request)
   {
    //Insert into orders table
    $order = Order::create([
        'buyer_id' => auth()->user() ? auth()->user()->id : null,
        'shipping_email' => $request->email,
        'shipping_name' => $request->name,
        'shipping_city' => $request->city,
        'shipping_phone' => $request->phone,
       // 'error' => null,
    ]);

    //Insert into order product table
    if ($order) {
        foreach(session('cart')  as $productId =>$item) {
           if (empty($item)) {
               continue;
           }
           OrderProduct::create([
            'order_id' => $order->id ?? null,
            'product_id' => $productId,
           // $products=DB::table('products')->where('id',$id)->get();
            'quantity' => $item['quantity'],
            //dd($item)
        ]);
       }
    }
```

CheckoutController(function)

```
    public function store(Request $request)
     {
    //Insert into orders table
    $order = Order::create([
        'buyer_id' => auth()->user() ? auth()->user()->id : null,
        'seller_id' => auth()->user() ? auth()->user()->id : null,            'shipping_email' => $request->email,
        'shipping_name' => $request->name,
        'shipping_city' => $request->city,
        'shipping_phone' => $request->phone,
       // 'error' => null,
    ]);

    //Insert into order product table
    if ($order) {
        foreach(session('cart')  as $productId =>$item) {
           if (empty($item)) {
               continue;
           }
           OrderProduct::create([
            'order_id' => $order->id ?? null,
            'product_id' => $productId,
           // $products=DB::table('products')->where('id',$id)->get();
            'quantity' => $item['quantity'],
            //dd($item)
        ]);
       }
    }

   //Empty Cart After  order created
    $cart = session()->remove('cart');
     return redirect()->route('confirmation.index')->with('success_message', 'Thank you! Your payment has been successfully accepted!');
     }
```

ProductController(function)

```
    public function viewOrders(User $user)
  {

        $products = Products_model::where('seller_id', '=', $user->id)->get();
        // all sells
        $sells = $user->sells;
        // all buys
        $buys = $user->buys;

    }
    //dd( $products);
    return view('orders')->with(compact('orders'));
```

My View File(blade)

```
  @foreach($sells as $sell) 
<tr>
  <td>{{$sell->orders}}</td>
  <td>{{$sell->products}}</td>
  @foreach($sell->orders as $order)
  <td>{{$order->created_at}}</td>
  <td>{{$order->shipping_name}}</td>
  <td>{{$order->shipping_city}}</td>
  <td>{{$order->shipping_phone}}</td>
  <td>
    <a href="">View Order Details</a>
  </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: the store function shown above, does it store and retrieve record?

Comment: Sorry for the question, but where from do you get the id: //Insert into orders table
    $user = User::find($id);

Comment: No it gives this error`"Undefined variable: id"` but if I remove this line` 'seller_id' => Products_model::where("seller_id", "=", $user->id)->get(),` I don't get seller_id.@samju

Comment: @Med.ZAIRI I was trying to get the seller_id to work but it doesn't

Comment: I guess, You should get the OrderProduct first, then, the Product and from that you could take the saller_id

Comment: How do I do that? @Med.ZAIRI

Comment: can you show your route ?? the error you are getting ``` "Undefined variable: id ``` is because it cant find $id. so wither you pass it as a request param or hidden field.

Comment: This is the error am getting https://imgur.com/JkhE2hv @alithedeveloper

Comment: Thats a correct behaviour ... Where does $id come from ???? do share your endpoint for that order .

Comment: it's coming from Users table @alithedeveloper

Comment: @alithedeveloper I have updated question, How to get this query for seller id so i can save to database?

Answer (score 0):

Let's see if we can find probably the easiest solution. I can see from your product model that it has a `seller_id` field. When you are looping over the products to display them, why don't you use a hidden input which has a value of `seller_id`? i.e.

```
@foreach ( $products as $product )
  <form> // assuming you will be creating a form for the buy button
     <input type="hidden" value={{ $product->seller_id }} />
     <button type="submit">Buy Now</button>
  </form>
@endforeach
```

Now in your Controller, you will have access to seller_id as

```
$seller_id = request('seller_id');
```

hope that helps

Comment: I have just updated question by adding checkout. blade form, because it gives error undefined variable products @alithedeveloper

Comment: sorry, i think are confusing yourself. show me how are you looping over the products and showing products to buyer .. the code i wrote should go in that file

Comment: Do you mean a loop where a buyer is checking out? or a loop where buyer can see all products

Comment: the loop where seller can show all the products for sale . A product for sale must have been created by a seller right ??

Comment: hope you can accept my answer and glad we got there . good luck

Comment: I mean I haven't fixed yet,

Comment: ` @forelse($products as $product)
         <img class="card-img-top" alt="Card image cap" src="{{url('images',$product->image)}}">
          {{$product->pro_name}}</p>
          
         @empty
         <h3>No Products</h3>
         @endforelse

Comment: I tried to add ` <input type="hidden" value={{ $product->seller_id }} />` to that loop and looks like isn't working am getting this error `General error: 1364 Field 'seller_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `orders``@alithedeveloper

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue that is every product must have a seller. If then, you should use buyer and seller relation with `OrderProduct` model not `Order` model.
Or you may collect seller by make relation with `product-seller`.

> First

remove `'buyer_id', 'seller_id',` from `Order model` and `orders migration`.

> Second

Add `'buyer_id', 'seller_id',` from `OrderProduct model` and `order_product migration`.

> Third

Transfer relation `buyer` and `seller` from `Order` model to `OrderProduct` model

> Fourth

When you create the `OrderProduct data`, you add `buyer_id` and `seller_id`. Finally catch and use them as you want.

> Fifth

Dont forget to update `buys` and `sells` relation `Order model` to `OrderProduct model` on `User model.`

> Sixth

you have to updatye orders relation on User model. It should be ,

```
public function orderFromBuyers()
{
    $this->hasManyThrough(OrderProduct::class, Products_model::class, 'buyer_id', 'product_id');
}
and 
public function orderFromSellers()
{
    $this->hasManyThrough(OrderProduct::class, Products_model::class, 'seller_id', 'product_id');
}
```

Note that, You cannot make them from one function.
Finally update any other things relation to these changes.

Comment: How do I do that@hasan05

Comment: Still don't know how to do that maybe you can help

Comment: I have just updated Order model and OrderProduct model am I correct at this point?@hasan05

Comment: I just figured out that, you must need to update your orders relation on User model. I am updating my answer again.

Comment: And also I have added functions that related @hasan05

Comment: Yeah this is correct. but you must correctly call them from controller or view.

Comment: Yeah I have updated questions with function have you seen it@hasan05

Comment: update on ProductController, $user->sells to $user->orderFromSellers, and $user->buys to $user->orderFromBuyers. And you much update your view file too.

Comment: I have updated question with my view blade loop(which is the seller dashboard)

Comment: Do I have to change anything in store function where there's buyer_id and seller_id. Because am getting this `General error: 1364 Field 'seller_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `order_product` (`order_id`, `product_id`, `quantity`,`

Comment: You have to handle this by your own. Or clear your question or queries clearly.

Comment: If you look in store function there's this line below the buyer_id, `'seller_id' => auth()->user() ? auth()->user()->id : null,` so the error comes from here even if I remove it still getting error

Comment: can you update the store function? on your question?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to `OrderProduct.php`

```
public function order()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Order::class);
}
```

Update product Controller

```
 public function viewOrders(User $user)
  {

      // $products = Products_model::where('seller_id', '=', $user->id)->get();
      // all sells
      $sells = $user->orderFromSellers;
      return view('orders')->with(compact('sells'));

  }
  //dd( $products);
```

Update your view to,

```
 @foreach($sells as $sell) 
    <tr>
        <td>{{$sell->orders}}</td>
        <td>{{$sell->products}}</td>
        <td>{{$sell->created_at}}</td>
        <td>{{$sell->order->shipping_name}}</td>
        <td>{{$sell->order->shipping_city}}</td>
        <td>{{$sell->order->shipping_phone}}</td>
        <td>
            <a href="">View Order Details</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

On CheckoutController (store) update to,

```
public function store(Request $request)
     {
    //Insert into orders table
    $order = Order::create([          
        'shipping_email' => $request->email,
        'shipping_name' => $request->name,
        'shipping_city' => $request->city,
        'shipping_phone' => $request->phone,
       // 'error' => null,
    ]);

//Insert into order product table
if ($order) {
    foreach(session('cart')  as $productId =>$item) {
       if (empty($item)) {
           continue;
       }
       OrderProduct::create([
        'buyer_id' => auth()->user() ? auth()->user()->id : null,
        'seller_id' => $products=DB::table('products')->find('productId')? $products=DB::table('products')->find('productId')->seller_id : null,  
        'order_id' => $order->id ?? null,
        'product_id' => $productId,
       // $products=DB::table('products')->where('id',$id)->get();
        'quantity' => $item['quantity'],
        //dd($item)
    ]);
   }
}

   //Empty Cart After  order created
    $cart = session()->remove('cart');
     return redirect()->route('confirmation.index')->with('success_message', 'Thank you! Your payment has been successfully accepted!');
     }
```

Comment: have a look this answer, @joh